# How to use parentheses in non-polymer molecule

Tags: subscripts, chemfig, chemistry, parenthesis

I would llike to draw the following molecule in tex using chemfig:

[image]

I tried in the following way:

```
\chemleft[ \chemfig{HOH_2C-[:-60]P^{+}(-[:-120]HOH_2C)(-[:-60]CH_2OH)-[:60]CH_2OH }\chemright]${}_2$\chemfig{SO_4^{2-}}
```

But it is not working properly. I get this result:

[image]

Does anyone could help me to get the subscripted number and the sulphate ion (SO42-) in the right place ?

Answer (score 2):

Here is an idea:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}        

\begin{document}

%\schemedebug{true}

\schemestart
  \subscheme{
    \chemleft[
    \chemfig{P^{+}(-[:120]HOH_2C)(-[:-120]HOH_2C)(-[:-60]CH_2OH)-[:60]CH_2OH}
    \chemright]
  }
  \chemfig{SO_4^{2-}}
\schemestop
\chemmove{\node at (c2.south east) {$\scriptstyle2$};}

\end{document}
```

[image]